# Jenkins stuck on installation on windows 7

Tags: jenkins

Jenkins is stuck on installation wizard at this stage for hours, I tried restarting and re running the wizard, same issue persists.
[image]

Comment: Are you running with appropriate permissions?  EUAC may want to you start the installer using run-as-administrator;  Are there any dialogs sitting behind this dialog?

Comment: @Jayan no there are no dialog box sitting behind this dialog, I am running the installer jenkins.msi as adminstrator from cmd.exe